# i.default is not a constructor - why is my import undefined in one file and valid in the next?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running into an issue with importing classes from different files in my TypeScript Node.js project. The classes being imported to certain files appear to be undefined. Here is my setup simplified:

I have three files in the same folder:

**product.ts**

```
import CommonController from './common';

export default class ProductController extends CommonController {}
```

**product-price.ts**

```
import ProductController from './product';

export const defaultCustomProductPriceController =
  new CustomProductPriceController({
    nestedQueries: [
      {
        nestedPropertyName: 'promotions',
        nestedPropertyClass: new PromotionController({
          nestedQueries: [
            {
              nestedPropertyName: 'freeProduct',
              nestedPropertyClass: new ProductController({})
            }
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  });
```

**custom-product-price.ts**

```
import ProductController from './product';

export const defaultCustomProductPriceController =
  new CustomProductPriceController({
    nestedQueries: [
      {
        nestedPropertyName: 'promotions',
        nestedPropertyClass: new PromotionController({
          nestedQueries: [
            {
              nestedPropertyName: 'freeProduct',
              nestedPropertyClass: new ProductController({})
            }
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  });
```

The error I am getting is in my `product-price.ts` file. When I try and run the code I just get the error:

> i.default is not a constructor

If I change the code in `product-price.ts` to not import the `ProductController` and instead just declare it inline in the file like so it does not throw any errors:

**product-price.ts**

```
import CommonController from './common';

class ProductController extends CommonController {}


export const defaultCustomProductPriceController =
  new CustomProductPriceController({
    nestedQueries: [
      {
        nestedPropertyName: 'promotions',
        nestedPropertyClass: new PromotionController({
          nestedQueries: [
            {
              nestedPropertyName: 'freeProduct',
              nestedPropertyClass: new ProductController({})
            }
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  });
```

I am baffled as to what is going on as I have used this pattern a lot in my app and had no issues with it.

Why would `ProductController` be importing as undefined in one file and perfectly fine in the next?

**EDIT** As requested here is the full import tree generated by madge:

[image]

[Here are the exact files I am working with](https://file.io/1CEzjzodeZtG)

Comment: This is a typical sign of circular dependencies being imported in the wrong order.

Comment: Please post the complete module structure with all declarations, imports and exports, not a simplified one, to provide a [mcve]. What are `CommonController`, `PromotionController` and `CustomProductPriceController`? Why are *product-price.ts* and *custom-product-price.ts* exactly the same code?

Comment: I think you are right @Bergi. What would be a way of generally getting around circular dependency importing order?

Comment: The general way is to avoid circular dependencies in the first place…

Comment: The bounty (500 reputation points(!)) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: @redhouse87 I'd be happy to write a more extensive answer but please address my second comment by [edit]ing the question

Comment: @Bergi does the newly attached image of my import tree help?

Comment: @redhouse87 Not really, I fear. While I can't spot any circular dependencies in it, that might be just because there are too many arrows to follow. Instead, we need a [mcve] as code. Also can you please address why *product-price.ts* and *custom-product-price.ts* are exactly the same code, is that just a copy-and-paste mistake?

Comment: @Bergi I have added a link to the exact files I am using https://www.file.io/txrh/download/zk8MdwVUDIYL

Comment: @redhouse87 That returns an error for me. Please [edit] your question to include all the relevant bits

Comment: Sorry try again now @Bergi

Comment: I have also updated the tree iamge that shows where the error is coming from

Comment: The updated madge image shows a circular dependency between *lambda/controllers/product-price.ts* and *lambda/controllers/product.ts*. Again, please update the code snippets in your question, [do not post a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a ["barrel files"/(index.ts)](https://steven-lemon182.medium.com/are-typescript-barrel-files-an-anti-pattern-72a713004250) to group imports that are later re-exported.

This pattern can sometimes cause [circular dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) issues if you're not cautious.

In this case, you probably messed up the order of the imports.

Your last example worked because you avoided using the `barrel file` and referenced it directly.
But the downside is that you gave up on separating it into a different file.

In order to break the circle, avoid the circular dependency issue from the start, and still preserve modularization:

You should avoid importing from index when the classes are dependent on each other.
Instead, You should import it directly from the specific module (file).
By doing that, you will avoid the circular dependency issue.

```js
import CommonController from './common/{{the-path-where-common-controller-is-defined}}';

export default class ProductController extends CommonController {}
```

See more:

- [How to fix nasty circular dependency issues once and for all in JavaScript & TypeScript](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de)
- use [madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge) library to visualize and find circular dependency issues

Comment: Hi there, I followed your advice and used madge to visualize circular dependencies which it showed in red text in my image above. I switched to using an index that imports/ exports all my controllers. This got rid of the red errors in madge however the same issue still persists

Comment: FYI I was originally importing directly from the specific controller file however this was also causing an error. The article you linked suggests to follow the index pattern

Comment: Here are the files I am using https://www.file.io/txrh/download/zk8MdwVUDIYL